# Spring-boot dependency not working with gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I'm following the tutorial at http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/ and trying out gradle for the first time along with it. 
The script is throwing an error when I include the `spring-boot` dependency. Here's the snippet from my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

`$ gradle tasks` fails with the error:

```
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rabbit-mq-example'.
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/gradle/api/Task;
```

This points at the line `apply plugin: 'spring-boot'` when I run it with the `--debug` flag.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your build file works for me. What version of gradle?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, September 9, 2013 8:44:25 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_75 (Oracle Corporation 24.75-b04)
OS: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic amd64

Comment: Let me upgrade gradle and check. I think that could quite possibly be the issue. Thanks @frhd

Comment: Oh my, that's a very antique version of gradle. Probably installed through linux packages?

Comment: Yup. That's the culprit I believe. Will check on it post lunch and accept your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link you provided, the requirements for `spring-boot` are:

- JDK 1.6 or later
- **Gradle 2.3+** or Maven 3.0+

Comment: Had a similar issue. The reason was an older version of Gradle. Updated it with help from http://wtanaka.com/node/8079 . Works fine now

Comment: Great find, @NakulSudhakar. I usually download the versions manually into /opt. This way I'll also read the release notes :)